# NLTK PortStemmer missing positional argument

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I have been experimenting with nltk, and I do not understand what my mistake is.`

I tried this:

```
from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer

stemmer = PorterStemmer
examples = ["cars", "eating", "quickly"]

for w in examples:
    print(stemmer.stem(w))
```

And Python returns this:

```
TypeError: stem() missing 1 required positional argument: 'word'
```

Could anyone explain to me what I am doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You forgot to call the constructor: `stemmer = PorterStemmer()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `()` to `PorterStemmer` since it is a class instantiation and it should work:

```
from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer

stemmer = PorterStemmer()
examples = ["cars", "eating", "quickly"]

for w in examples:
    print(stemmer.stem(w))
```

stdout:

```
car
eat
quickli
```